# Rails 4 Migration | Add Table with Reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I am attempting to create a `Collaboration` table in my Rails 4 project, but I've run into an issue.  I wish it to belong_to a single user, the collaborator.

I ran the following command to generate the model and the migration, which I've also copied below.

```
rails generate model Collaboration project:references collaborator:references accepted:boolean
```

Migration:

```
class CreateCollaborations < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :collaborations do |t|
            t.references :project, index: true, foreign_key: true
            t.references :collaborator, index: true, foreign_key: true
            t.boolean :accepted

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :collaborator, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I updated the Collaboration model to include `, class_name: 'User'` as shown above.  Similarly, I updated the existing `Strategy` model to include a `has_many :collaborations`

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collaborations
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get the following error reported.

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "collaborators" does not exist
```

I'm a bit puzzled as to wy this is happening.  **Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!**  Thank you. :)

EDIT:

Adding code for my `User` model as well.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    authenticates_with_sorcery!

    has_many :projects
    has_many :collaborations
end
```

I edited out validations for fields such as password, email, etc to try to remove clutter.

Comment: Post your User.rb (in particular, the relation bits).

Comment: The more I think about, this, the stranger it seems... Normally, you'd use that `class_name:` alias if you were trying to use the same key in more than one relationship, yet your collabortion is only using user once. I really think trying to use `belongs_to :user` is in order at this point, even if only for diagnostic purposes. For all I know, what you're doing is fine, and I just haven't ever encountered it in the wild.

Comment: @MarsAtomic - Yeah I see what you're saying.  I tried to build a small test project to focus on this issue because I'm experiencing something similar in a larger project.  The same issue was replicated in this small issue.

Answer (score 16):

This part of your migration:

```
t.references :collaborator, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

will try to create a [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) inside the database so that the `collaborator_id` column of the `collaborations` table will be guaranteed to be `NULL` or contain the `id` of a column in the `collaborators` table. You can't create that FK until the `collaborators` table exists.

The error you're getting is:

```
relation "collaborators" does not exist
```

and that's just telling you that you don't have a `collaborators` table but you're trying to reference it.

You need a migration to create the `collaborators` table *before* you create your `collaborations` table.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. Just to clarify, he's aliasing user as collaborator, so he needs to make sure his create_users_xxxxx.rb migration takes place before this create_collaborations_yyyyy.rb migration.

Comment: Hmm, I have a users table which was set up earlier in my project.  I tried to add a separate migration to add a collaborator reference to the collaborators table however I ran into the same error with that migration as I encountered with the first.

Comment: @MarsAtomic - That's exactly right!  The issue is because I am trying to reference the users table while aliasing it as "collaborator".  Still working through the errors though.

Comment: So `collaborations.collaborator_id` is supposed to be a `users.id` value? How do you feel about using `t.references :user` instead?

Comment: @muistooshort - That's something I could look to use if I can't get this sorted out.  I'd like to get it figured out as it's currently constructed first, if possible.

Comment: As near as I can tell, you can (1) use `user_id` as the column name (i.e. `t.references :user`), (2) don't use an FK (i.e. `foreign_key: false`), or (3) add the database FK by hand with a bit of SQL. (1) is the most Railsy I suppose, (2) is a shortcut to broken data in your database, (3) will require switching your `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`. The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-references) don't seem to offer anything else. I do (3) because I use all kinds of things in the database that AR doesn't understand.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5, at least, you can use foreign_key: {to_table: ... }} as follows.

```
create_table :messages, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.references :from_user, type: :uuid, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :users, on_delete: :cascade}
  t.references :to_user, type: :uuid, references: :user, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :users, on_delete: :cascade}
  t.text :body, null: false
  t.timestamps
end
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for being late, but essentially it's all about convenience, remember that's the essence of rails. so; every reference should be targeting the table that should be in the plural (since a table holds many "objects") therefore, you must make the reference to plural so rails will generate a reference to a singular object. button line, your migration should look more like;

```
class CreateCollaborations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :collaborations do |t|
        t.references :projects, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.references :collaborators, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.boolean :accepted

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now, if you follow the conventions, then you should have no problem with the rest, just keep in mind that `belong_to` is to a singular object and `has_many` is to a plural object.

PS: I would not use past reference for the column, like `accepted`

Happy Coding